# Cannot transpose a 2D matrix in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am a beginner in programming. Learning 2D arrays in C now. I encountered a question asking to transpose a 2D matrix (i.e a 2D array). The book's suggested answer suggested using another array.

I was trying to find a way to do the same without the other array.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void printAr(int[3][3]);
int main()
{
    int A[3][3];
    printf("Enter the numbers: \n");
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
    printAr(A);
    printf("Now transposing------------------\n");
    for(int f=0;f<3;f++)
    {
        for(int h=0;h<3;h++)
        {
            int t=A[f][h];
            A[f][h]=A[h][f];
            A[h][f]=t;
        }
    }
    printAr(A);
    return 0;
}

void printAr(int B[3][3])
{
    for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
    {
        for(int l=0;l<3;l++)
        {
            printf("%d ",B[k][l]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter the numbers:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

-------------------------------
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
Now transposing------------------
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

What am i doing wrong?
And why can't it transpose it?

Comment: @harold: Only ⅔ of it was transposed twice. The diagonal elements were only swapped with themselves once. 

Comment: Beginner's mistake: every element gets swapped twice.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Not every element was swapped twice, just those off the diagonal.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: according to the IEEE regulations, swapping an on-diagonal element gets a double charge.

Comment: @overkill Imagine what happens for f=1 h=2, then what happens for f=2 h=1 in your code.
Try this `for(int h=0;h<f;h++)` (instead of `for(int h=0;h<3;h++)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a transpose operation, every element of the upper-triangular submatrix gets swapped with one of the lower-triangular sub-matrix, and the diagonal elements don't move.

So a quick fix is

```
for(int f=0;f<3;f++)
{
    for(int h=0;h<3;h++)
    {
        if (h<f)
        {
            int t=A[f][h];
            A[f][h]=A[h][f];
            A[h][f]=t;
        }
    }
}
```

But you can do that in a slightly better way...

Comment: you can move `h < f` into the second `for` loop header.

Comment: @Barmar: please don't spoil.

Comment: Someone else already put that in a comment on the question

Comment: @Barmar: extra reason not to spoil.

Comment: And `f=0` can be skipped, because no `h` is going to match

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, i totally overlooked that it will be transposed twice. Yes , maybe there is a  better way , but right now i am trying to get the basics right :)

Comment: The better way is extremely basic and was already spoiled twice.

Answer (score -1):

Your transpose logic is wrong because your two loops will transpose the array twice resulting in the same array you have begin with. One of the solution is to copy the result in another array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void printAr(int[3][3]);
int main()
{
int A[3][3];
int B[3][3];
printf("Enter the numbers: \n");
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
{
scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
}
}

printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
printAr(A);
printf("Now transposing------------------\n");
for(int f=0;f<3;f++)
{
for(int h=0;h<3;h++)
{
int t=A[f][h];
B[f][h]=A[h][f];

}
}
printAr(B);
return 0;
}
void printAr(int B[3][3])
{
for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
{
for(int l=0;l<3;l++)
{
printf("%d ",B[k][l]);
}
printf("\n");
}
}
```

If you want to transpose without using second array try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void printAr(int[3][3]);
int main()
{
int A[3][3];
printf("Enter the numbers: \n");
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
    }
}

printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
printAr(A);
printf("Now transposing------------------\n");
for(int f=0;f<3;f++)
{
    for(int h=f+1;h<3;h++)
    {
        int t=A[f][h];
        A[f][h]=A[h][f];
        A[h][f]=t;
    }
}
printAr(A);
return 0;
}

void printAr(int B[3][3])
{
for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
{
for(int l=0;l<3;l++)
{
printf("%d ",B[k][l]);
}
printf("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: The book already suggested using a second array, the OP is trying to figure out how to do it with just one array.

Comment: If its not a square matrix you cannot do it without a second array .

Comment: @VikramAditya: In-place transposition of a non-square array induces a permutation that may be annoying to deal with but is certainly possible, subject to aliasing the memory as array types of two different geometries.